# How to define attribute (in class diagram)as an array of four elements?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, attributes, uml, class-diagram, papyrus

How to define attribute (in class diagram)as an array of four elements using `Papyrus` as a modelling environment?

## Does that possible in Papyrus?

Here is the class:

[image]

## How to edit the properties of attribute in the following properties view to represent an array of four elements??

[image]

Comment: I haven't work with this application, but try `String[]`, and as I know usually the size of the arrays is not initialized with its declaration, but you would do it so with initializing(default value/sequence diagram), like `+names:String[] = new String[4]`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Papyrus specifically but you have a field called Multiplicity on the right. Change it to `4` if your array has to always have exactly 4 elements or `0..4` if it can have at most 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is much, much more easy.

[image]

If these elements belong ONLY here, use composition - filled diamond. If they can exist by themselves, use Aggregation - empty diamond.

Comment: thanks @Gangnus What if the array consists of four integer numbers ?

Comment: You will simply put intStaticArray into body of ClassicWorkDesk block. The line will be int[1..4]:intStaticArray. If you will set it as static in any  modeller, it will be underlined. If you use more simple tool, underline by hand.